# Adding a random delay for a Linux command

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, puppet

I am using [func](https://fedorahosted.org/func/) to perform parallel commands on our servers.

The other day, we had an issue when a service restart of `puppet` via `func` made all our severs hit our `puppetmaster` at the same time.

**My question:** How can I execute the same exact command on a set of servers while adding a delay before it's executed on the individual servers?

E.g.: `random_delay && service puppet restart`

I am interested in the `random_delay` part of the command.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`sleep $((RANDOM % MAXWAIT))` where MAXWAIT is the maximum desired delay in seconds.

Comment: Seems to get stuck on "1" a lot if you echo that out... Thoughts?

Comment: Noticed this as well. Try this, for x in 1 2 3 4 5; do RANDOM=$x; i=$((RANDOM%10)); echo $i; sleep $i; done Obviously, MAXWAIT in S19N's answer is similar in effect to 10 in my answer. Change the RANDOM seed and add puppet code to whatever you desire of course.

Comment: @CoreyS. $RANDOM is seeding off the last value, hence the looping (I've gotten stuck on 5/6/7, 2/7, and 5). `sleep $((RANDOM % MAXWAIT))` is the correct way. I'll edit the answer as such.

Comment: This is called *splay* in Pro Puppet. It is used to prevent a *thundering herd*, where many machines are doing the same thing simultaneously. In addition to this, I had success with cron scheduling using `fqdn_rand`.

Comment: This seems to depend on bash-specific extensions. In `dash` `echo sleep $((RANDOM % 900))` returns `sleep 0`. This means it is not safe to use in `#!/bin/sh` scripts or places like crontab. (The problems seems to be that `dash` does not understand `$RANDOM`)

Answer (score 5):

```
sleep $((RANDOM))
```

The `RANDOM` will return a value between 0 and 32767
If you need to set a lower and upper limit to your sleep you need to define two other variables as follows:

```
MINWAIT=10
MAXWAIT=30
sleep $((MINWAIT+RANDOM % (MAXWAIT-MINWAIT)))
```

Comment: With `MINWAIT=10` and `MAXWAIT=11` (only 1 unit appart), the command `echo $((MINWAIT+RANDOM % (MAXWAIT-MINWAIT)))` will always display `10` (id. `$MINWAIT`).

Answer (score 2):

I quite like S19N's innovative, yet less than ideal solution.  I only say it's less than ideal, as it's still largely non-deterministic when stuff will actually happen.  I'd much rather be able to guarantee when stuff will happen, and what stuff will happen when it does.

Puppet orchestration is actually a *hard* problem.
One of the "best-practice" solutions is to use [MCollective](http://puppetlabs.com/mcollective/) which will not only allow you to configure when puppet runs on your cluster of machines, but you can also use it for other similar orchestration problems.

Answer (score 2):

```
0 */12 * * * root perl -e 'sleep int(rand(43200))' && service puppet restart
```

This will sleep a random amount between 0 seconds and 12 hours (43200 = 12 x 60 x 60) every 12 hours